# Display (not save to disk) Detailed Stop Errors on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bsod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get more info out of the uninformative Windows 8 BSOD?](https://superuser.com/questions/492422/how-to-get-more-info-out-of-the-uninformative-windows-8-bsod)

So Windows 8 has this new consumer-friendly STOP error screen where half the display is taken up by a frowny face, and what few technical details are provided are in a very fuzzy font that hurts my eyes.

I'm not a consumer, and I don't want to see frowny faces.  I want to see the detailed error description and stack traces.  Is it possible to re-enable detailed technical error messages **on screen**?  If so, how?

(If not, details remain available after loading the crash dump into `windbg` and issuing the `!analyze` command... assuming of course that the crash didn't prevent writing a dump file to disk.  For failures of the NTFS filesystem or disk driver stack, dumping the data on-screen remains the only viable way to make it available.)

---

Microsoft provides [instructions for re-enabling the original detailed BSOD screen on Technet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2929742/stop-error-information-isn-t-displayed-on-the-blue-screen-in-windows).  Updates may be required for this to work correctly.

Comment: There's the event log too, if you have that option selected in Advanced Settings under Startup and Recovery. I think it's selected by default.

Comment: currently there is no known way to get the old one back. Use WinDbg to see the cause.

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate of the other question.  Viewing the information after reboot (from Event Log or minidump) is not a solution, when the error prevents writing information to the hard disk.  My question specifically requires getting the information on the screen.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I've kicked off the reopen voting process in light of your most recent comment.

Comment: It's still the same question IMO, perhaps just not with answers you like. :)  Perhaps consider placing some comments and a bounty on the original to garner different/better answers.

Comment: @techie007: I do thank you for finding the related question.  But there's nothing there that helps with troubleshooting bugchecks involving the disk, which prevent storage of debug data onto the disk.

Comment: I must agree that it's the same question

Comment: @Luke: the other question sounds like (based on the accepted answer) "where can I read more about troubleshooting stop errors?", which information is useful but quite different from the debug data contained within the error.

Comment: @BenVoigt But the question itself is the same. Just because the answer isn't what you're after doesn't mean it's a different question. Remember, you can edit your question, or their question, and people can then vote to accept the changes if that is what the author meant.

Comment: @Luke: I have edited my question, to make it clear that I'm not looking for ways to access the stored information after a reboot (since storing it may fail).  But that was part of my question from the start, even if it wasn't in bold or in the title.

Comment: I still want an answer to this.