# How to see Windows 8 BSOD error parameters?

Tags: windows-8, bsod

Where can I find [the four hexadecimal STOP error parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551961.aspx) that [used to be shown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death#Meanings) in older versions of Windows on the Blue Screen of Death whenever a kernel bug check occurs?
I can't find them in Windows 8.

Also, is there any way to see **which module** caused the error, as was also possible before?

Comment: possibly related, [How to get more info out of the uninformative Windows 8 BSOD?](http://superuser.com/q/492422) the parameters should be saved in Event log I think

Comment: @Sathya: I looked, but I couldn't find them in the event log as they claimed. There's nothing with ID 1001. Maybe it's different on Windows 8?

Comment: You should always use WinDbg to see the cause. So I don't care about this screen.

Comment: @magicandre1981: "I don't care about this screen" isn't exactly a helpful comment. Can you describe how to use WinDbg to see the cause instead of closing the question? Sathya already linked to the other question and I already said the answers there didn't help me for Windows 8, not sure why you're marking this as a duplicate

Comment: @Mehrdad watch this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can highly recommend [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html):

[image: BlueScreenView screenshot]

From the site:

> BlueScreenView Features:
>
> - Automatically scans your current minidump folder and displays the list of all crash dumps, including crash dump date/time and crash
>     details.
> - Allows you to view a blue screen which is very similar to the one that Windows displayed during the crash.
> - BlueScreenView enumerates the memory addresses inside the stack of the crash, and find all drivers/modules that might be involved in the
>     crash.
> - BlueScreenView also allows you to work with another instance of Windows, simply by choosing the right minidump folder (In Advanced
>     Options).
> - BlueScreenView automatically locate the drivers appeared in the crash dump, and extract their version resource information, including
>     product name, file version, company, and file description.

It doesn't require installation and runs on both 32 and 64 bit Windows (XP up)

**UPDATE**

Here are some links with information about the new "Automatic Memory Dump" option in Windows 8:

- http://www.thewindowsclub.com/automatic-memory-dump-settings-windows-8
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/09/12/windows-8-and-windows-server-2012-automatic-memory-dump.aspx

Comment: Have you actually used this on Windows 8? The screenshot shows Windows XP, but I just tried it on Windows 8 and I don't see anything in the list (there doesn't seem to be a minidump or MEMORY.DMP file even though I have "Automatic memory dump" turned on with that path).

Comment: @Mehrdad I must admit I haven't needed to use it as (touch wood) my Windows 8 hasn't BSODed yet. However, according to the author "BlueScreenView works with Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8, as long as Windows is configured to save minidump files during BSOD crashes."

Comment: Do you have a C:\Windows\Minidump folder? Or a "C:\Windows\Memory.dmp" file? If you have the Memory.dmp file, you may need to go to Options -> Advanced Options and "Load a single Minidump file"...

Comment: Ah I just got it working -- turns out the "Automatic" memory dump option is very stupid, it's equivalent to doing nothing (doesn't generate any dump file). If I set it to something else then it works fine, thanks!

Comment: (-1): Bluescreenview is crap and displays often wrong and useless data. Use Windbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Answer (score 0):

It should be recorded under the Windows heading in Problem Reports. Search for 'problem' in Settings and select 'View all problem reports'.

Comment: Hmm the list is empty unfortunately... is there a setting I need to turn on?

Comment: @Mehrdad There is 'Problem Reporting Settings' in Action Center but I don't think that should affect the recording. As you haven't got a minidump either, I guess it's failing in a way that prevents the data being recorded.